Linear time alg for checking if numbers in a list are close
Suppose we have an unsorted list of $n$ integers. What is the best algorithm we could use to detect if there exists a pair of ints that are 'close' to each other. Close being within some arbitrary int range.
ie) let's say we define close as within $5$. Then [6, 28, 953, 21, 11] would be 'True' since there exists a pair (6, 11) that are within 5.
Brute force is trivially $O(n^2$). We could sort the list and check the neighbors of each index and get something in $O(n log(n))$ but can we do something in linear time?
One thing I'm thinking which would be $O(c*n)$ where c is the 'close' threshold is each time we see a val, we add it to our set. And once it's in our set we check all numbers from val-c to val+c and if any one of those are also in our set, we know there is a close pair. Anything better?

Do you care more about worst-case performance and theoretically provable time bounds, or running time on "typical"/"normal" inputs?

Yes.  You can do it linear time in practice.  I'll focus on a practical solution, without worrying about theoretical worst-case running time (which gets messier).  The approach will be to work in two stages.  In each stage, we'll "bucket" the points into buckets of width $2\Delta$, and then check within each bucket for close points.
Notation: Suppose we define "close" as being within $\Delta$.  Let $n$ denote the number of integers in the input.  Let $h_0:\mathbb{Z} \to \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be an ordinary hash function.
Stage 1: Define a set of "buckets"
$$\ldots,[-2\Delta,0),[0,2\Delta),[2\Delta,4\Delta),[4\Delta,6\Delta),\dots,$$
Conceptually, we'll associate each input number to the bucket it falls in.  Concretely, we'll hash each input $x$ using a hash function $h_1$, defined as
$$h_1(x) = h_0(\lfloor x/2\Delta \rfloor).$$
Build an array $A[1..n]$ of linked lists (initially empty), and scan over all elements of the input.  For each element $x$, append $x$ to $A[h_1(x)]$.  Then, for each $i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, sort the list of elements in $A[i]$ and check whether any pair is close.
Stage 2: Do the same, but now with the buckets
$$\ldots,[-3\Delta,-\Delta),[-\Delta,\Delta),[\Delta,3\Delta),[3\Delta,5\Delta),\dots$$
and the hash function
$$h_2(x) = h_0(\lfloor (x+\Delta)/2\Delta \rfloor).$$
Intuition: Why does this work?  Well, if we have two input elements $x_1,x_2$ that are close (within $\Delta$), then they will either fall into the same bucket in Stage 1 or the same bucket in Stage 2.  So it suffices to check, in each stage, for close pairs within each bucket.  We don't have to check pairs that are split across two different buckets.
If we didn't have to worry about hash collisions from $h_0$, checking for close pairs within a bucket would be trivial.  A bucket containing 0 or 1 elements does not have a close pair (it does not have any pair).  A bucket containing 3 or more elements is guaranteed to have a close pair.  And for a bucket containing exactly 2 elements, it is easy to just check whether those 2 or close.
In real life, $h_0$ might introduce hash collisions, so a list $A[i]$ might include elements from more than one bucket.  But assuming $h_0$ is any good, it's unlikely that it includes more than a few buckets.  Sorting takes care of that.
Details: If we don't care about degenerate inputs, the above is probably fine.  But to make this robust to degenerate inputs (e.g., the same value repeated $n$ times), I suggest that you use a specific sorting algorithm.  In particular, use recursive QuickSort, and in each recursive call, check whether the first two elements are close.  If they are close, abort the entire process and return those two.  I believe this suffices to handle all degenerate inputs.
Correctness: If there are two close points, then they will fall within the same bucket in either Stage 1 or 2, and the above procedure will find them.  The procedure won't output false pairs.
Running time: The running time should be $O(n)$, i.e., linear.  In particular, you can hash all the points and add them to the array in linear time.  Now it is unlikely that any list $A[i]$ contains items from more than a few buckets.  By the above, most buckets either have a close point that can be detected easily, or have $O(1)$ size.  So most lists $A[i]$ will have $O(1)$ size and sorting and checking for close pairs can be done in $O(1)$ time.  And for degenerate inputs, if there is a list $A[i]$ that contains many elements, then the recursive QuickSort should very quickly find a close pair and abort (if $A[i]$ contains elements from 1 bucket, then one of the two top-level recursive calls should find a close pair; if $A[i]$ contains elements from $k$ buckets, then you should need to go to level at most $k$, hence need at most about $2k$ recursive calls, and if $h_0$ is any good, the chances $A[i]$ contains $k$ buckets is exponentially small in $k$).
Theoretical bounds: If you want theoretically provable running time bounds, you'll need to make some modest tweaks.  You'll need to replace $h_0$ with a universal hash function, and you'll need to prove a theorem.  I expect you'll find that the expected running time is $O(n)$, and moreover, the chances that the algorithms takes more than $c \cdot n$ steps is exponentially small in $c$.
Addendum: This is closely related to the problem of finding the closest pair of points in 1D.  Surely someone must have studied this, but I can't find anything with a quick web search, because the search primarily turns up results about the 2D case, or trivial $O(n \log n)$ algorithms for the 1D case.
Finding a deterministic linear-time algorithm is likely hard.
